# The GNU screen is unresponsive, seems blocked

Tags: linux, freeze, kill, gnu-screen

GNU Screen seems to freeze. Unable to enter user input.

I was using GNU screen and when I pressed the screen it became unresponsive. I can execute all the GNU screen commands, but can't enter user input. I don't want to kill this screen as I have important work and I don't want to lose it.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/byobu-screen-constantly-freezes-in-putty

Answer (score 155, accepted):

In the commands below, replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with whatever your escape key is for screen commands.

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>, which is the sequence to unblock scrolling.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> is the sequence that blocks scrolling, which makes screen seem like it freezes.

Comment: Well, it worked but only in one screen, in the other one it quit :(

Comment: You Sir, just made my day :)
GNU screen documentation didn't come up when googling "gnu screen freeze" :/

Comment: I had the same problem. Only one screen was frozen, which made me believe the problem was "screen-specific". Indeed, I had accidentally pressed Ctrl-A s.

Comment: I'm so used to using CTRL+A to go to the front of the command line to add ````sudo```` (since I forgot to start with it) that when I'm using screen, I lock it all the time!  As previous comment says, ````CTRL+A q```` mostly works, sometimes exists the screen. Wish CTRL+A was not the default, on servers I use alot I change it to the "ESC" key.

Comment: Combine this nasty little beast with PuTTY's awful Ctrl+S which sends a XOFF and it really makes me fear the "s" on my keyboard. It's evil. Oddly the PuTTY keystroke is Ctrl+Q to send a XON... "q" is the savior. Thank you, 6 year old answer.

Comment: In my case, it sometimes freezes without `Ctrl-A s` and `Ctrl-A q` doesn't help. Neither bash's own unlock. Closing my console and reopen the connection is the only thing I can do.

Comment: I changed my command character to "Ctrl+o" with `escape ^Oo` in my .screenrc file

Comment: I am SO glad to have found this. I was using osm2pgsql to import a big osm.pbf file into the database and used `screen` to keep it running on an EC2 instance. The process was stuck at around 95% of the way, and it was no longer showing any progress, CPU 0%. After checking strace, it showed it was stuck on a `write(...)` syscall. I must have pressed the 'freeze scrollback` keys by mistake earlier. Now I try unfreezing and it worked again! So happy!

Answer (score 69):

When **using PuTTY**, you can get an apparently freezed screen if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. 
This sends an [`Xoff` signal](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Xon-Xoff-X-on-X-off-or-XON-XOFF) blocking the terminal's output.

The solution is to **press** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to send the `Xon` signal.

Comment: Also worked for me on ROXTerm on Linux -- screen was locked and gave me a login prompt.

Answer (score 10):

The above works great if that is your issue.

This could also happen if you're ssh'd into another machine and haven't been to the window in awhile, then when you go back it's frozen. To fix this, you can try the following:

1) Create a new window

```
Ctrl-a c
```

2) ssh into the box where you ssh'd into the box in the window that's frozen.

3) Find the process the ssh is running under:

```
ps aux | grep <remote_box_on_frozen_screen>
```

or

```
ps aux | grep <your_user_id>
```

4) Kill the process

```
kill <process_id>
```

Comment: Don't know how I got things into such an unresponsive state, since usually ctrl-q works for me, but I had to do this and lose my work. +1 for the break-here-in-case-of-emergency advice

Comment: More often than not any frozen SSH connection can be forcefully closed by pressing `Enter`, then `~` and then `.` (see also [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/29952/130326)).

Answer (score 3):

When you do `screen -ls` the first number of the screen name is the process id. So if the output is

```
There is a screen on:
    21605.pts-0.Random-server   (11/12/2017 11:44:15 PM)    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-kg.
```

Then this will kill it:

```
kill 21605
```

Notice the number for the kill command is the same as in the `screen -ls` output.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using backtick commands in status line - that is, if your `.screenrc` has something like this:

```
backtick 1 0 60 /some/script.sh
```

then you want to be sure that the script is fast: apparently backtick execution blocks all IO to screen.

If you make changes to the config, you'll need to restart the screen session (as the config applies only to new sessions).

Comment: I had a backtick script running just fine for a very long time. Did a kernel update from 4.20.4 -> 5.4.80 and all of a sudden I faced this issue. For whatever reason my script which calls ```sensors -u``` is much slower with the new kernel... quite the rabbit hole this sent me down.