# Commands in PuTTy are unresponsive

Tags: ssh, putty

I have successfully connected to my server via puTTy and I am entering commands but they are unresponsive. I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: If a command is successful, usually there is no success message. There is only error/warning messages when something goes wrong. It depends on the command, obviously. Can you describe what "unresponsive" means? It could also mean delayed, or you get disconnected when you type a command, or...

Comment: Unresponsive means nothing happens. I have no experience with putty or ssh but I'd have expected that when a command is  entered the command line interface will return a few lines to show that it has been executed. So far this has not been the case.

Comment: Also I do expect the command line to return something. I am running the following command for example '#/scripts/whoowns exampledomain.com' and I expect to see who owns the domain name. Is there something I am missing. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that command (not very familiar with SSH myself). If you have connected to your server, logged in with your username/password, the command line should show the directory you are working in. You can type `ls` to see a list of current files in the directory, or `cd /` to go to the root folder. If these commands work as expected, then it's working. anything after that is specific to your host/script and I don't know how to help you there.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PuTTY, and get an apparently freezed screen, you could have accidentally pressed `ctrl + s`. This sends an Xoff signal blocking the terminal's output.

The solution is to press `ctrl + q` to send the Xonsignal.

See also: [The GNU screen is unresponsive, seems blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367669/the-gnu-screen-is-unresponsive-seems-blocked)